# PHP string containing PHP tags puts HTML comment around string

Tags: php

```
$string1 = '<?php This is a paragraph ?>';
$string2 = "<?php This is a paragrahp ?>";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($GLOBALS);
```

When I click view source I see this: `<!--?php This is a paragraph ?-->` for both strings. Why is this happening?

Comment: It's wrong. i can't see any `<!--?php This is a paragraph ?-->` in source ...

Comment: It's not, https://3v4l.org/e8aGW. Maybe your browser or a plugin is transforming it?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome